# How do I make an image repeat by modifying the css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to repeat an image `.middle-container-line` in relation to the left and right container.

Basically as more images are inserted, I want the `.middle-container-line` image to repeat y axis (down) and follow the images that are inserted.

So i dont want to specify a height using pixals as I want the upload of  images to determine how long down the line repeats.

Is this possible?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/F9R4P/

CSS:

```css
.main-container {
    width:600px;
}
.image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}
.left-container {
    height:1000px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:39%;
}
.middle-container-line {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:100%;
    min-height:200px;
    background: url("http://socialmediatalentincubator.com/chartego/img/live-feed/green-vertical.png") center repeat-y;
}
.right-container {
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    width:39%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Not getting your question quiet well...

Comment: your fiddle seems to show what you are after or is the question about how to make all the columns the same height?

Comment: Yes sorry, im trying to make the columns same height without using a specified height. i want the upload of images to determine how long  the line is... does that make sense?

Comment: so the image of class `.middle-container-line` should be repeated based on either of the classes on left and right?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually combine the whole code together like this:

```
.bgclass{
    background:url(images/mybg.jpg) repeat;
}
```

For css reference background you can have a quick look in here:
http://www.overpie.com/css/tutorials/css-background

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Jquery Library to find out max height. Either left or right div will have max height.

Add jQuery library in your page, if not added. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/F9R4P/8/

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="left-container">
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
</div>
<div class="middle-container-line"></div>
<div class="right-container">
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
    <div class="image">this is image</div>
</div>
```

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var leftHeight = $( ".left-container" ).height();
     var rightHeight = $( ".right-container" ).height();
    if(leftHeight>rightHeight)
      $(".middle-container-line").css('height',leftHeight);
    else
        $(".middle-container-line").css('height',rightHeight);
```

});

```
.main-container {
    width:600px;
}
.image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}
.left-container {
    height:1000px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:39%;
}
.middle-container-line {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    border:1px solid green;
    min-height:200px;
    background: url("http://socialmediatalentincubator.com/chartego/img/live-feed/green-vertical.png") center repeat-y;
    display:table-cell;
}
.right-container {
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    width:39%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: jQuery is a bit overkill for this layout, CSS alone will do it. However, it does illustrate an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
.middle-container-line
{
background-image:url("http://socialmediatalentincubator.com/chartego/img/live-feed/green-vertical.png");
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

taken from: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the middle div from the HTML completely, float the right side div to the right and put the bg image on the container.

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/T4dRa/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left-container">
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
        <div class="image">this is image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;

   background: url("http://socialmediatalentincubator.com/chartego/img/live-feed/green-vertical.png") center repeat-y;
}

.image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}

.left-container {
    height:1000px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:39%;
}


.right-container {
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:right;
    width:39%;
    height:100%;

}
```

Comment: In the floated child containers, `height: 100%` will have no effect and `height: 1000px` is not really needed.  Your containers will adjust their heights according to the number of images added to the left/right child containers.

Comment: Yeah...I knew that but I didn't want to mess with the existing CSS other than to show the basic resolution to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it using table-cells:

```
.main-container {
    width:600px;
    display: table;
}
.image {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
}
.left-container {
    display: table-cell;
    width:39%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.middle-container-line {
    display: table-cell;
    width:20%;
    border:1px solid green;
    background: url("http://socialmediatalentincubator.com/chartego/img/live-feed/green-vertical.png") center repeat-y;
}
.right-container {
    display: table-cell;
    width:39%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6fhfG/

Instead of using floats, apply `display: table` to your parent container (`.main-container`),
and then `display: table-cell` to `.left-container`, `.middle-container-line`, and `.right-container`.

The resulting layout will have 3 columns that are all the same height, and the overall height will be determined by either the left or the right container depending on how many images are in each.

By using CSS tables, the three columns will always stay on a single line, depending on whether or not you need a responsive design instead of fixing the width of the parent container.

**Note:** Apply `text-align: center` to `.left-container` and `.right-container` is you want the images centered horizontally within each column.